# Arched rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I have a rectangle with some dashes on it sitting somewhere  not in the origin (0,0), as:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % just to show the origin, not really there. 
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.06);

    % a simple thin rectangle
    \draw[fill=black!50] (3.1,-2.2) rectangle (3,2.2);
    % some lines
    \foreach \x in{0,0.1,...,4.4}
        \draw (3.1,-2.2+\x+0.1) -- (3,-2.2+\x+0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This draws a thin rectangle. I'd like however, this rectangle to be a filled arc, with the curvature/radius of its distance from the origin.

I know how to make line arcs, but how can I arc this entire thing?

Comment: Can you give a complete minimum example starting with `\documentclass[]{}` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: @AndréC done, nothing fancy really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With polar coordinates it is straightforward:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % just to show the origin, not really there. 
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.06);

    % a simple thin rectangle
    \draw[fill=black!50] (3.1,-2.2) rectangle (3,2.2);
    % some lines
    \foreach \x in{0,0.1,...,4.4}
        \draw (3.1,-2.2+\x+0.1) -- (3,-2.2+\x+0.1);

    \draw[fill=black!50] (0,0)  ++(-45:3) arc (-45:45:3) -- ++(45:0.1) arc (45:-45:3.1) -- cycle;

    \foreach \x in {-45,-43,...,45}{
        \draw (0,0) ++(\x:3) -- ++(\x:0.1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```